# SWIFT - Coredata Delete relational records

Tags: ios, core-data, swift

I'm using core data with table A having one to many with table B.
Trying to delete records from table B which are related to record in table A.
When I was trying to delete, it only removes the relation i.e. the relational ID from records of table B. Not deleting the records.

Please suggest any code or reference.

I’m trying this

```
func removeList(values: NSSet) {
        var items = self.mutableSetValueForKey("relationEntToB");
        for value in values {
            items.removeObject(value)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you set your delete rule to 'cascade' in the data model?

Comment: Yes already added delete rule to 'cascade', but still not working

Comment: Please show some code for the deletion

Comment: @pbasdf edited question with code

Comment: `removeObject()` is intended only to update the relationship, not to delete the object from the database.  You need to call `deleteObject(value)` on your context instead.

Answer (score 3):

I believe [pbasdf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3985749/pbasdf) is correct.  If you're trying to remove `B` objects (where `A` to `B` is a *one-to-many* relationship) by calling function `removeList(values: NSSet)`, you need to use `NSManagedObjectContext.deleteObject()` which actually removes the object from data store.

If you think about it, `NSMutableSet.removeObject()` only removes the object from the `NSSet` and NOT from object store.  So the entry you intended to delete will remain.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
if let optionArray = YourManagedObject.mutableSetValue(forKey: "yourKey") {   
        for object in optionArray {
            appManageContext.delete(object as! NSManagedObject)
        }
    }
```